# Applying FP/Categorical terminology to non-FP languages

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming, category-theory

In my continuing effort to finally wrap my brain around advanced FP/categorical concepts, I've been reading dozens of articles and tutorials; what I have concluded is that:

1) Category Theory and Software Engineering use the same words in different ways; or, I think, Software Engineering uses category theory terms far too loosely.  (Functor, Monad, Applicative, and so forth.)

2) The operations around functors/monads are like pizza toppings: Every single library/tutorial has its own terminology that is borrowed somewhat incorrectly from every other, and no one can agree on anything.

3) Using Haskell to explain these concepts is useless to anyone who doesn't already know Haskell, because Haskell is built to make implementing them so trivial that it doesn't translate back out to languages that don't.

To that end, I want to lay out what I THINK the full set of terminology is in a non-Haskell-ish language (a pseudocode that resembles Javascript, sort of), and the numerous variations I've seen, and invoke Cunningham's Law to ask people to correct me when (not if) I demonstrate I am still not grokking it.

I will update the post with corrections where possible, but if you're coming to this later please be sure to read the comments, too.

---

If you want to translate your basic category of types into a category with "more contextually useful stuff" (which could be logging, null/optional handling, IO awareness, etc.), there are a couple of things you need, in practice.

First, you need an operation that lifts a value from your type to your enhanced type; category theory canonically calls this `unit`.  Haskell calls it `return`.  In a non-typeclass language, it's usually implemented as the constructor of an class that represents "type plus context"; Eg, `Maybe::constructor(val)`.  I have also seen `pack`, `lift`, and `of` as static method names here that wrap the constructor.  I've even seen `join`, which seems confusing with `join` as an alias of `bind` (below).

Second, you need a way to lift a unary function that takes a type T and returns the same type T to one that takes an enhanced version of T and returns an enhanced version of T.  Haskell calls this `fmap`.  Non-functional languages variously call it `map`, `apply`, `then` (if dealing with promises) or other things and assume that it will *also* be invoked when passed.  So you end up with no simple lifting function, but a "lift and use" operation.

The combination of `unit` and `fmap` constitute a *functor*, because they're lifting a type and function to the enhanced type category.

You also need a way to convert the enhanced value back to unenhanced; In Haskell this is just referencing the value.  In Rust it's called `unwrap`.  Other names I've seen include `flatten`, `value`, `get`, etc.  Sometimes there are multiple of these, such as Java's `orElse` and `orElseGet`, but those are convenience utilities not part of the core definition.  Other non-core operations that vary depending on the type of enhancement may be `isNothing` (Maybe), `logs` (for a Writer), or some IO related stuff.

Third, you need a way to convert a unary function that takes a type T and already returns an enhanced T, and allow it to take an enhanced T as its parameter.  This is a different operation from `fmap`.  Haskell and others call this `bind`.  In less powerful languages I've seen this also called `flatmap`, `map`, `join` and `chain`.  (`flatmap` because it first calls `flatten` to extract the value, and then calls `fmap`, then rewraps it into an Enhanced T.)

In canonical Javascript, `then` works with *either* a T->T or a T->Enhanced function, effectively combining `fmap` and `bind` into a single function named `then`.  Whether this is wise or not is a subject of some debate.

A function from T to Enhanced is (half of) a functor.  `bind` allows you to combine those together in a way that follows the monoid laws.  Thus, `bind` is a monad (a monoid for (endo)functors).  Strictly speaking, from a category theory point of view only `bind` is a monad.  In Software Engineering, though, it's quite common to refer to the whole set of things as a monad, since they're usually implemented as methods.  `bind` also gets called `join` or `chain` in other languages.  That is:

```
class Enhanced {

    private value;

    // These two are technically a functor.
    func constructor(value) { ... }

    static func fmap(function from T to T) returns function from Enhanced<T> to Enhanced<T>

    // Doesn't have a name in Haskell, but object-y languages always have it:
    public func value() returns the value itself

    // Also called `apply` in some versions.
    public func map(function from T to T) returns the result of applying the function to value

    // Strictly speaking, this is the monad.
    // Also called `join` or `chain`.
    public function bind(function from T to Enhanced<T>) returns the result of applying the function to value, but wrapped in Enhanced

}
// Colloquially, programmers call the whole thing a "monad", aka a monad pattern.
```

Which is equivalent to the following in a more type-robust functional language (Haskell, F#, etc.):

- `Maybe value` ; `Either value`; or various other type constructors, equivalent of unit or the object constructor.
- `fmap`, which can be a free-standing function because of more robust typing
- `bind`, but it is so common it gets turned into an operator >== and the type system figures out which bind to use, since there's several.

Fourth, you need a way to lift non-unary functions.  Haskell auto-curries everywhere so... it just sorta falls out naturally.  In other languages it's generally a separate function (or static method), `liftA2` for a 2-argument version, `liftA3` for a 3-argument version, etc.  That function is equivalent of `fmap` (or is it `bind`? Not sure here?) but for a binary and trinary function, respectively.

I... don't quite grok how you would then incorporate a `liftA2`ed function into an enahnced type, other than manually currying it.

Which then means if you want to have, as an example, a zero-division-safe arithmetic, you'd do:

```
func add(x, $y) => x + y;
func sub(x, $y) => x - y;
func mult(x, $y) => x * y;

func div(x, y) => {
    if (y == 0) return new Maybe();
    return Maybe(x / y);
};

func liftA2(fn) {
    // I am definitely wrong here.  Please advise.
    return func (a, b) => Maybe(a).map(fn).bind(b);
}

maybeAdd = liftA2(add);
maybeSub = liftA2(sub);
maybeMult = liftA2(mult);
```

At this point I run out, because I feel I'm missing a step along the way here.  I suspect something related to Applicatives, because I haven't fully wrapped my head around those.  (I haven't gotten to that chapter in Bartzoz's book yet.)

So that's where I am.  Can anyone advise on where I'm going off the tracks and what the next piece of railroad tie is?

Comment: You keep saying "you need this, you need that". Need them for *what*? And in case I think you're getting of the tracks, what would constite a useful answer to you?

Comment: I think you need to be a lot more precise and careful here. You start by considering "your basic category of types" that you want to "translate" (into some other category that is not described). What is this "category of types", and what does "translate" mean here?

Answer (score 1):

Let me comment on your description. To make notation more definite, I will talk about types `T` and `E(T)`, where `E` stands for your "enhanced context". For example, `E` could be `List` or `Promise` or something else.

> The combination of unit and fmap constitute a functor

Usually `unit` is not required for a functor, just `fmap`. If you have `unit` then it is called a "pointed functor".

> You also need a way to convert the enhanced value back to unenhanced

If you have a function `E(T) -> T`, the functor `E` is called "co-pointed". But this is not always possible. An example is `List`: you cannot always extract values from a list because a list could be empty. So, `List` is a pointed but not a co-pointed functor. You cannot have a function `List(T) -> T` that always returns a result for arbitrary types `T`.

Most often, it makes sense to extract values into another "enhanced context", i.e., into another functor. For example, you try to extract a value but if it is not possible you generate an error.

> flatmap because it first calls flatten to extract the value, and then calls fmap

It's the other way around: it first calls `fmap` and then `flatten`. The function `flatten` does not actually extract values from a functor, it has the type signature `E(E(T)) -> E(T)`.

About this:

```
func liftA2(fn) {
  // I am definitely wrong here.  Please advise.
  return func (a, b) => Maybe(a).map(fn).bind(b);  
}
```

This looks almost correct. The operation `liftA2` needs to transform a function of type `(A, B) -> C` into a function of type `(E(A), E(B)) -> E(C)`. You can indeed implement this operation using `bind` and `fmap`. I'm not sure what programming language you are using where you had functions like `func add(x, $y) => x + y`, so I can't tell you how to write the code correctly in that language. In Haskell this would look like:

```
liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> E a -> E b -> E c
liftA2 f ea eb = bind (\k -> fmap k eb) (fmap f ea)
```

But this is probably too terse to be clear.

"Applicative functor" is such `E` that has `liftA2` (but does not necessarily have to be a monad).

So, generally you are on the right track. You are listing the various properties of functors. There are about four or five useful kinds of functors that you will eventually discover.

One way of proceeding systematically is to begin with the "map/filter/reduce" style of programming. First, you find that you can write iterative code without explicit loops, just using `map`, `filter`, `fold`, `zip`, and `bind`. Then you study the properties of those functions: what laws do they need to satisfy in order to be useful for programming, and what data structures can support those functions. You will find, for example, that `List` has all those methods but the simple type `E(a) = Maybe (a, a)` does not have `bind` that could satisfy the laws.

Category theory is not of very much help at this point, other than providing language to talk about "functors" and "natural transformations".

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone advise on where I'm going off the tracks
>
> You also need a way to convert the enhanced value back to unenhanced

No, generally speaking you don't have such conversion. For example, in JS you cannot get a value out of a Promise, you have to resolve the Promise `.then(f)`. Same goes for Haskell, you cannot (without unsafe stuff) get a value `a` out of a Monad say `IO a`, since there is no monad interface function like: `m a -> a`. However, you can use `>>=` (bind) `m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`  to chain computations on such values, by providing a function `a -> m b`.

Comment: At some point you need to convert back, otherwise you can't, well, print anything to the screen.  You need access to the something.  That's not the part I'm tripping up on; it's the subtle terminology differences and the way to deal with non-unary functions.

Comment: "At some point you need to convert back, otherwise you can't, well, print anything to the screen." Well you can return a new state of the world with something printed on the screen: "The universe as part of our program" -https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/IO

Comment: That's still not the question I'm asking, and plenty of implementations (eg, Rust) do include an unwrap command.  The inconsistent terminology is the main thing I'm trying to confirm, and how to handle non-unary functions.  Can you advise on that?

Comment: I can confirm the inconsistent terminology. This problem also exists in math, where different authors prefer different notation and sometimes different terms (depending on their background). In the end it's all about the definition, if two different terms have the same definition, then they are the same thing. I prefer to use the terms from category theory, so I say Functor instead of Mappable.

Comment: LiftA2 is defined as: `liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c`. So it takes a binary function (also called bivariate function, or function of two variables) and two Applicative Functors and returns an Applicative Functor. However, you don't need liftA2 for safe arithmetic. A safe division can be defined as: ```safeDiv :: Integer -> Integer -> Maybe Integer```
```safeDiv x 0 = Nothing```
```safeDiv x y = Just (x `div` y)```